# ComboBox SelectedIndex lost on content change

Tags: wpf, vb.net, combobox

I have a ComboBox which content might change. The issue is when the content is changed, 1) i lose the previous selectedIndex, and 2) SelectedIndex is set to -1.
I would like an MVVM solution, not some solution involving code-behind.
I can have the SelectedIndex set to 0 on content change, but -1 is not a valid value for my model.

What i did as a 'trick' was to have the setter of the property bound to SelectedIndex to set the value to 0 when the value is set to -1. So now i don't have incorrect value in my model. But the ComboBox does not display the "0"th item, rather an empty box.

What could i do to have my ComboBox display the first item (index 0) when its content changes ?

```
  <ComboBox Name="WeeksComboBox"      IsEditable="False"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Weeks}"
                                      SelectedIndex="{Binding WeekNumber}"
                                      >
```

Weeks is a Notifying property that is a list of strings. It is changed when i change the Year property. WeekNumber is a notifying property of type integer. Now when it is set to -1, i set the corresponding private member to 0 to avoid wrong value in my model.

Comment: I suspect you are rebinding as that will set the selected index to -1.  Please post the code where you bind and where you change content.

Comment: When you say "it is changed wehn i change the year" do you clear that list out - if so that is when it is getting set to -1 as there are no values (until you add the new values).  If you are doing a clear then add you will need to set WeekNumber = 0 after the add (I would set the Public rather than the private).  And I would use and ObservavleCollection over a list.

Comment: Using an ObservableCollection will automatically notify its items changes (add, move, remove). Also, if you replace the currently selected item, the reference to the old one will be lost and the index will be -1 therefore. You can use a small ViewModel to represent that WeekNumber, and if the item value changes, change is internal number and notify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always do that in the code-behind when I change the source

For example,

```
Weeks = GetNewWeeksCollection();
WeekNumber = 0;
```

An alternative is to use the `PropertyChange` notification

```
void MyViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Weeks")
        WeekNumber = 0;
}
```

Of course, that only works if you actually set `Weeks` to a new collection. If you simply clear it and reset it, you'll have to use the `CollectionChanged` event

```
void Weeks_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
        WeekNumber = 0;
}
```

Comment: i was changing _WeekNumber (the private integer backing WeekNumber) and it didn't work, it work with changing WeekNumber !!!??? still there is an issue : WeekNumber changes from, say, 5 to !!-1!! then to 0. and -1 is not valid index...

Comment: @VincentPiel The private version of the property probably does not raise the `PropertyChange` notification so the UI doesn't know the value has changed and it should update. And an index of `-1` means that no item is selected, so it is still a valid value. More than likely changing the source resets the `SelectedIndex`, so the `ComboBox` is responsible for setting the value to `-1`, but since you set it to `0` right after you shouldn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use trigger:

```
    <ComboBox Name="WeeksComboBox" IsEditable="False"
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding Weeks}"
                                   SelectedIndex="{Binding WeekNumber}" >
        <ComboBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItemId}" Value="-1">
                        <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Style>
    </ComboBox>
```

You can define trigger like this for all comboboxes. Google for more info about styles and triggers.

Comment: What happens when the Weeks is empty and Value="0" is invalid?

Comment: You'll lose the binding if you do it that way